# How to commit files in svn and automatically transfer them to multiple application servers

Tags: linux, webserver

I have multiple application server.
Is there any way using which i can commit files in svn and all the committed files automatically get transferred in all my application server.

Also if possible can something like this be possible
I commit files and firstly these files get transferred only to production server and when i check everything is working file , then by some command they gets transferred to my live servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a continous integration server.
We are using Jenkins (see http://jenkins-ci.org/ ) for tasks like that. You can run tests, copy files to different servers, execute scripts (e.g. if you want to start/stop/redeploy your application, ...).